# Call Skype user based on email address

Tags: android, api, skype, user-management

I'm working on a Java Android app that initiates Skype calls based on users' email addresses.

How do I call a Skype user based on their email address?
I didn't find any tutorial about it in the Skype developer's network.
Do I need to fetch their skypeUserName from an email? How do I do that?

Thank you :)
Nur

Comment: Did You get Any info regarding this.. ?